# How do exec and flock work together in bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, exec, flock

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
exec {LOCK} > foo.out
flock -x ${LOCK}
...
```

I understand that exec without an argument simply redirects all the output of the current shell to the foo.out file. Questions:

1. What does the first argument to exec {LOCK} mean, given that it seems to have a special significance because it is in curly braces (but not ${...}).
2. What is the value of ${LOCK} and where did it come from (I don't think that I defined this variable)?

Comment: Curly braces around a single word don't have any special meaning. Are you sure it's not `exec ${LOCK}`?

Comment: That script doesn't make any sense to me. It's going to try to run the program named `{LOCK}` and replace the shell script process with that execution.

Comment: Where did you find this code snippet?

Comment: That might be just `fd's`, file descriptors being used.

Comment: I am certain that there is no $ around {LOCK} in the first line. I think that script inside curly braces could run as a subshell, since there is no $ before the opening curly brace. The code snippet comes from a script invoked by Jenkins but I don't see the calling script add that variable either.

Comment: `echo Hi {LOCK}< <(echo Bye) ; cat <&$LOCK`

Comment: `exec {fd}< <(env); while read -ru"$fd"; do :; done; declare -p fd`

Comment: @Jetchisel - could you elaborate

Comment: Not sure which version of `bash` that was added and I have used that feature a long time ago bu I have abandoned it, so I have forgotten how and why did I ever used it :-)

Comment: If you do `echo /dev/fd/${LOCK}` you should probably see what is the value of `{LOCK}` well at least in the script.

Comment: It can even be a tempfile:  http://sprunge.us/Qp8WuO

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Jetchisel. Here is what I found and it is beginning to make partial sense. It does use fd's as you surmised. The line ```exec {LOCK} > foo.out``` creates an empty file while also setting the ${LOCK} variable to an fd. ```flock -x ${LOCK}``` locks on that fd. Still not sure how the variable ${LOCK} came to be and which fd is the one being locked on. I suspect that foo.out is kept open and the fd may be for that open file.

Comment: Better ask the author of the script what he/she has in mind about that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid or useful bash. It will just result in two different error messages.

Instead, the intended code was this:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
exec {LOCK}> foo.out
flock -x ${LOCK}
...
```

It uses:

1. `{name}>` to open for writing and assign fd number to `name`
2. `exec` to apply the redirection to the current, keeping the fd open for the duration of the shell
3. `flock` to lock the assigned fd, which it will inherit from the current shell

So effectively, it creates a mutex based on the file `foo.out`, ensuring that only one instance is allowed to run things after the `flock` at a time. Any other instances will wait until the previous one is done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally figured out:

`exec {LOCK}> foo.out`
changes stdout of the current shell to the file foo.out. The fd for the open file is set the variable ${LOCK}. Setting fd to the {LOCK} variable is a feature of bash.

`flock -x ${LOCK}`
is simply locking using the file descriptor.